# Uninstalling an app called Menu Editor and other related apps to menu editor

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I recently started using it (about a month ago). I downloaded this app called Menu Editor. I added some kind of launchers from it and I'm not sure how to delete those launchers and the Menu Editor app.

[image]

Comment: Details such as your OS/release may help, plus how you added the 'Menu Editor' (ie. is it a *snap*, *appimage*, etc or standard package?, and if if not from Ubuntu repositories, where you got it from?).

Comment: i dont remember

Comment: the code i used

Comment: How you uninstall software safely depends upon how you originally installed it. Search your memory.

Comment: not in the memory i searched

Comment: Hey Devang Ghodkhande! Did you install 'Menu Editor' from Ubuntu Software or by some other way? BTW, what's the Ubuntu version which you're using?

Comment: @technastic_tc By the looks of things Devang is using Ubuntu 20.04 and the Menu Editor application is an apt package that came from the default Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Force remove and reinstall Menu Editor app.

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq menulibre
sudo apt install menulibre
```

The "New Launcher" menu entries in the Dash were put there by the Menu Editor app (*menulibre*) from the default Ubuntu repositories. They can be removed by selecting the launcher in Menu Editor and clicking  Delete on the Menu Editor toolbar as shown in the below screenshot. You can open Menu Editor from the terminal by typing `menulibre` or by clicking Menu Editor's icon in the Dash which is marked by a red arrow in the screenshot in your question.

Since you have created 7 "New Launcher" menu entries in the Dash with Menu Editor you must search in all the categories in the left pane of Menu Editor until you find every "New Launcher" entry and then delete each "New Launcher" entry by clicking the trash can icon one by one.

[image]

Search for the Menu Editor app in the Software app and uninstall it by clicking the  <kbd>Remove</kbd>  button. You can also uninstall it from the terminal:

```
sudo apt remove menulibre
```

Comment: But, in order to open the "Utilities" menu you need to add a launcher, so its like a never ending process

Comment: @DevangGhodkhande In my Ubuntu installing Menu Editor automatically added a Menu Editor icon to the Dash which is marked by a red arrow in the screenshot in your question, but you can also open Menu Editor from the terminal by typing `menulibre`.

Comment: no but as you see in your screen shot the utilities menu at the top cannot be opened unless you add a launcher

Comment: Try opening Menu Editor from the terminal with the command `menulibre`

Comment: nothing different happened it was the same thing as you open it from the menu

Comment: We've been wasting a lot of time on what I thought may be what Jean Paul Sartre called "mauvaise foi", but in this case that wasn't the problem. The problem is that you can't access Menu Editor app in any way, so force remove and reinstall Menu Editor app and then you will be able to launch it and solve the remaining problems. I added the commands to do this to the beginning of my answer.